# What is @iswrapper decorator from ibapi.utils?

Tags: python, ib-api

As the title suggests, what does `@iswrapper` decorator do? I see it quite often in the official docs, but can't find any explanation of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at the source

```
# I use this just to visually emphasize it's a wrapper overriden method
def iswrapper(fn):
    return fn
```

It's convenient when your class is mixed up with some EWrapper methods.